# Using Google analytics and Google firebase at the same time

Tags: android, analytics

I have recently implemented Firebase Analytics to an Android application. Before that I was using Google Analytics and everything was working correctly. Since I implemented Firebase Analytics, I am not receiving any data in Google Analytics - I only get data in Firebase Analytics. I have left the code for GA and added also calls for FA but only FA works. Does anyone know what the problem is?

I have read that you can do this with Google Tag manager but it looks like a lot of work and is something I would not like to do at the moment. Can I send data to both Firebase and Google Analytics without using the tag manager?

Note that I am using the Json file from Firebase and passing the UA-* property for GA in the initialization of the tracker object.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use both FA and GA analytics together, there are 3 simple actions to do:

1. delete your `global_tracker.xml` (or analytics.xml, whatever xml where you did store your tracking code UA-xxxxxx);
2. in your GoogleAnalyticsApplication.class add private string with your tracking code: `private static final String PROPERTY_ID = "UA-xxxxxx-x";` and pass this string as parameter to `mTracker` object creation like this: `mTracker = analytics.newTracker(PROPERTY_ID);`.
3. update `analytics_service` parameter in your `google-services.json` this way:

   "analytics_service": {
                 "status": 1
               },

that's all. after this you will have both GA and FA analytics work together correctly.